# Getting two xml elements sepearted by comma in the same row

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want an xslt file which operates on xml file to get two prod-id and article-number in one line separated by comma. This should happen only where
Product has no items.

My input xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <prod-id>P16653</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <article-number>233060</article-number>
        <languagedata>
            <language>
                <languageid>en-GB</languageid>
                <buying-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</buying-description>
                <customer-long-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</customer-long-description>
            </language>
        </languagedata>
        <items/>
        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
    <product>
        <prod-id>P16659</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <article-number>345940</article-number>
        <languagedata>
            <language>
                <languageid>en-GB</languageid>
                <buying-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</buying-description>
                <customer-long-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</customer-long-description>
            </language>
        </languagedata>
        <items/>
        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
    <product>
        <prod-id>P16755</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <article-number>11060</article-number>
        <languagedata>
            <language>
                <languageid>en-GB</languageid>
                <buying-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</buying-description>
                <customer-long-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</customer-long-description>
            </language>
        </languagedata>
        <items>
            <item>
                <item-id>i16754</item-id>
                <item-status>CREATED</item-status>
                <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
                <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
                <content-status>New</content-status>
            </item>
        </items>
        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
    <product>
        <prod-id>P16633</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <article-number>21069</article-number>
        <languagedata>
            <language>
                <languageid>en-GB</languageid>
                <buying-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</buying-description>
                <customer-long-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</customer-long-description>
            </language>
        </languagedata>
        <items/>
        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
    <product>
        <prod-id>P16785</prod-id>
        <product-status>CREATED</product-status>
        <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
        <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
        <content-status>New</content-status>
        <article-number>9881061</article-number>
        <languagedata>
            <language>
                <languageid>en-GB</languageid>
                <buying-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</buying-description>
                <customer-long-description>FENDI L VELOUR SWEAT PANTS BEIGE</customer-long-description>
            </language>
        </languagedata>
        <items>
            <item>
                <item-id>i16757</item-id>
                <item-status>CREATED</item-status>
                <validation-status>Valid</validation-status>
                <duplication-status>Unique</duplication-status>
                <content-status>New</content-status>
            </item>
        </items>
        <created-on>2016-08-12T11:30:00</created-on>
        <created-by>Administrator</created-by>
        <last-changed-on>2016-08-04T17:34:00</last-changed-on>
        <last-changed-by>ap0712</last-changed-by>
        <delete>false</delete>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want output as

```
P16653,233060
P16659,345940
```

I am using the following xslt which I got from this forum and tried to modify it but it is giving me only article-number and not both

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="products/product[not(items/item)]/prod-id/concat(local-name(), ' ', .)" separator="&#10;"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="products/product[not(items/item)]/article-number/concat(local-name(), ' ', .)" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Why is `P16633,21069` excluded from your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="products/product[not(items/item)]/concat(prod-id, ',', article-number)" separator="&#10;"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 I get

```
P16653,233060
P16659,345940
P16633,21069
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/products">
    <xsl:for-each select="product[not(items/item)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="prod-id"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="article-number"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hor257k Thanks but while running your file, I am getting an error: No supported xslt version found

Comment: @adit It's only a **template**, not the entire stylesheet **file**. Use it to replace the template in *your* stylesheet.